# How to get CRX file of a published in Microsoft Edge Web Store (Chromium Based)

Tags: microsoft-edge

My extension was published on the new Microsoft Edge Store. I want the CRX file of that extension. How to get that?

I don't want to use the 'pack extension' present in the browser as the CRX created like this gives security errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Edge developer dashboard, but CRX files for Edge can be downloaded via:

`https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D[EXTENSIONID]%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc`

Where `[EXTENSIONID]` must be replaced with the extension ID, found in the URL of the Edge extension store.

Here is an example:

https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-c/bhmdjpobkcdcompmlhiigoidknlgghfo

Has its CRX available via:

https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dbhmdjpobkcdcompmlhiigoidknlgghfo%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for the Edge chromium extension from Edge store, we could only use the "Pack Extension" method to get the CRX file.

Please refer to the following steps to generate the CRX file, it's not showing the security error on my side (Microsoft Edge Version 81.0.416.72 (Official build) (64-bit)).

1. Launch Edge Chromium browser
2. Navigate to "**edge://extensions/**"
3. Enable the **Developer mode**.
4. click the "**Pack Extension**" button
5. In the popup window, Click the **Browse** button to select the extension root directory.

   By default, we could find the installed extensions from the following folder (using Edge chromium stable version without profile, change the {username} to yours)

   `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions`

   [Note] If we are using the Microsoft Edge Beta/Dev/Can version, the extensions folder path as below (change the {username} to your account name, change {edge version} to Edge Beta or Edge Dev):

   `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\{edge version}\User Data\Default\Extensions`

   [Note] If you add multiple profiles, we could visit the extension from the related Profile folder, like this (change the {username} to your account name, the {number} starting from 1):

   `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile {number}\Extensions`

   Then, based on the extension id and the above extension folder to find the related extension root directory (it should contain the "manifest.json" file). The private key file is optional, but if we don't select a private key file, it will auto generate a private key file.

   [image]
6. Click the "Pack extension" button to start packing the extension, after finishing, we could find the CRX file from the following folder (change the {username} and {Extension ID} to yours):

   `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions\{Extension ID}`

Comment: i tried this method. after installing the CRX file in Microsoft edge, I is disabled with the message "This extension may have been corrupted."
I'm using Edge Version 84.0.516.0 (Official build) canary (64-bit).

Also is there any way I can use these CRX files in Google Chrome??

Comment: I have reproduced the problem on my side, it seems that this is an Edge browser issue, I suggest you could submit a feedback about it (Open Edge chromium browser, navigate to "edge://extensions", click the Send Feedback menu and enter the feedback, finally click the Send button). Besides, for the CRX files get from Edge Extensions, it will show this error "This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge". So, perhaps you have to create a Chrome version extension.In my opinion, you could try to reinstall the extension from the extension store.

Answer (score 0):

Please create app on page https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole.

Then upload zip file, after download crx from that